# Shear a 3D Model in Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I´m starting to use libgdx in Android to draw some 3d Models. Right now I have 2 shear matrices that I would like to apply to a cube I have. The problem is that I don´t know where I have to do the matrix multiplication. When working on pure OpeGL ES2 I know I do all this in the onDrawFrame with the modelMatrix in my Renderer class. But in libgdx I have a modelInstance and the `render()` method. Can anyone tell me how can I apply the matrix multiplication to the model I have?

```
public class Basic3DTest implements ApplicationListener {
    public PerspectiveCamera cam;
    public ModelBatch modelBatch;
    public Model model;
    public ModelInstance instance;

    @Override
public void create () {
    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();

    cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    ...
    cam.update();

    ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
    model = modelBuilder.createBox(5f, 5f, 5f, 
            new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.GREEN)),
            Usage.Position | Usage.Normal);
    instance = new ModelInstance(model);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    modelBatch.begin(cam);
    modelBatch.render(instance);
    modelBatch.end();
}

@Override
public void dispose () {
    modelBatch.dispose();
    model.dispose();
}
```

Comment: `instance.transform` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you that´s exactly what I needed :)